# Invalid Directory about make migration on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

When I do this command: `php bin/console make:migration`

this shows an error like:

> In InvalidDirectory.php line 15:
>
> Cannot load migrations from "D:\DEV\the_platform_back/migrations"
> because it is not a valid directory

Answer (score 0):

php bin/console make:migration command create migrations file named Version210....php in src/Migrations

Verify if this folder exists, with the uppercase.